# Showing list of applications and asking user to select one to show more details in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I am working on Chatbot development using Microsoft Bot Framework. The requirement is that when user provides her details like account number and date of birth, the chat bot should show her a list of application under her account. From that list, she should be able to pick one of the application and the chat bot should fetch it's details like date of application, status etc.

My API for the data has been setup and API returns list like:

```
[
{
"id":"123",
"applicaitonID":"AA123",
"Status":"InProgress"
},
{
"id":"456",
"applicaitonID":"AA456",
"Status":"Completed"
},
]
```

From above response, Chatbot should create a table that shows applicationId as hyperlinks.

Upon clicking on that link, chatbot should fetch details of the specific application.

I do understand very basics of MBF (Microsoft Bot Framework). Any example/suggestion will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pretty straight forward given that you already have the api in place.

Best approach in your case in my opinion is to look into the proven samples and continue from there.

Number 44 is a good place to start your journey"

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/README.md